# Rotate the wheel to a specific point

Tags: ios, rotation, transform

In this wheel we have 6 pieces. The top of the wheel is the specific point. The specific point gives information of pieces. Now it gives information of the blue piece. So if i click on one of the piece for example purple, i need that purple piece to goes to the specific point and automatically go into the given information about the purple piece.

[image: Wheel]

```
    CGFloat topPositionAngle = radiansToDegrees(atan2(view.transform.a, view.transform.b));
```

1. -180 - pink
2. -120 - blue
3. -60 - orange
4. 0 - purple
5. 60 - yellow
6. 120 - green

Now the topPositionAngle shows -120 = blue, when purple comes to the specific point it shows 0.

```
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:view];
    CGFloat currentAngle = radiansToDegrees(atan2(currentTouchPoint.x, currentTouchPoint.y));

    CGFloat angleTransform = ???
    CGAffineTransform current = view.transform;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
        [view setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(current, angleTransform)];
    }];
```

How can we get the automatically rotation to the specific point? Just like *Dansk Bank* app (see the following youtube link) something similar to the video from 0:21 - 0:25 min.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hulBh_KNGjE

Comment: your proplem looks similar to Raywenderlich tutorial. check the link it might help you [Click here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit) It was nice helping you. If you want entire project download it from Github link. [Click to download project](https://github.com/funkyboy/How-To-Create-a-Rotating-Wheel-Control-with-UIKit)

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but I already been thru Raywenderlich tutorial, which only explain about the rotation of wheel. I need a specific one, which can rotate when I click on a place, and that area should enter into a specific place. Like if I click on the purple area, it should rotate all the way up to the blue area, which is the "main area". So what ever you click on should move to that specific place. Is there any code for that?

Comment: It doesnt look similar — it is a copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to Know touched Point Angle:

```
CGFloat touchedPointAngle = atan2f(touchPoint.y - centerSuper.y, touchPoint.x - centerSuper.x) + M_PI;

if ((touchedPointAngle < sliceInRadians) && (touchedPointAngle > 0)) {
        angleTransform = sliceInRadians;
} else if ...
```

Then you can transform.

Answer (score 0):

```
float fromAngle = atan2(m_locationBegan.y-img.center.y, m_locationBegan.x-img.center.x);
float toAngle = atan2(_location.y-imgDigits.center.y, _location.x-img.center.x);
float newAngle = wrapd(m_currentAngle + (toAngle - fromAngle), 0, 2*3.14);
angle = newAngle;

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newAngle);
img.transform = transform;
```

Use something like this. Hope this helps
Here u should know touch point and your specific point